# Random Increasing Number

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function(or just a piece of code) that will count from 0 to 100, while each number that the program will print will be greater than the previous one (like this:0,14,20,21,26,34,58,..100).What I made is just a function that will increase the number by 1 every 1 second.

```
    import time,random
def inumber(count):
    while count!=101:
          time.sleep(1.0)
          (random.randrange(0, 100))
          count=count+1;
          print(count)
inumber(0)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I make the number (0) increase randomly until it reaches 100.

Comment: You use `random.randrange(0, 100)` but you do nothing with the result.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to get a random number between 0 and 100 at each iteration, instead you want to adjust your counter to a random number between the current number+1 and 101 (the limit for [randrange()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) is the expect max number + 1).

```
import time
import random


def inumber(count):
    print(count)  # Print first number
    while count < 100:
        time.sleep(1.0)
        # Set count to a number between the next number and 101
        count = random.randrange(count+1, 101)
        print(count)


inumber(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time,random
def inumber(count):
    while count<=100:
        time.sleep(1.0)
        count += random.randrange(0, 100) # consider a number lower than 100 here
        print(count)
inumber(0)
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes. Remember to format code properly.